# How to click on Javascript using Selenium under perl $sel->click

Tags: selenium, perl, xpath, dom-events

I've been using Selenium IDE and Selenium Remote Driver to test a website.  When I export the file to perl and try running it I get error trying to open a link which is a Javascript.  Here's the code I've been trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan";
use Test::Exception;
use Env;

my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                                port => 4444, 
                                browser => "*firefox", 
                                browser_url => "http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/" );


$sel->open_ok("http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/" , undef, "Getting Webpage CPC");
$sel->set_speed("1000");            
$sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("10000");    
$sel->select_frame_ok("toolbar");

$sel->click_ok(" //a[contains(\@href,'javascript:goTo(overview.html');)] ");
#and tried this format as well
$sel->click_ok("//a[\@href='javascript:goTo('overview.html');']");
$sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("10000");
```

It says can can't find the element, I've been trying the use the Xpath as a locator, but just can't seem to locate.  Below is the html of the link I'm trying to click:

```
<title>CPC Toolbar</title>
        <script language="javascript" src="./toolbar.js"></script>

<tr>
    <td align="center" >
    <a href="javascript:goTo('overview.html');" onMouseover="libserv.src='icons/redlibserv.gif'" onMouseout="libserv.src='icons/bluelibserv.gif'"><IMG SRC="icons/bluelibserv.gif" name="libserv" width="100" height="20" border="0">
    </a>
    </td>   
</tr>
```

Any help with how implement this would be much appreciated.  As well in the WWW::Selenium module, it gives these xpath formats to use as locators:

```
xpath=//img[@alt='The image alt text']
xpath=//table[@id='table1']//tr[4]/td[2]
xpath=//a[contains(@href,'#id1')]
xpath=//a[contains(@href,'#id1')]/@class
xpath=(//table[@class='stylee'])//th[text()='theHeaderText']/../td
xpath=//input[@name='name2' and @value='yes']
xpath=//*[text()="right"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with Firefox 22 and selenium, unresolved at time of posting

Edit - Source: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5554

Comment: Thanks user1697631.  I've read that that as well.  Most people downgraded to FF21.  So I'm in the process of doing to that.  But that seemed to solve most of their soloutions.

Comment: Acutally, it seems there's a fix and need to download IDE 2.1.0.  More  info here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5841

Comment: Still can't get it to work when I run it from the terminal.  Any further help would be great

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've found so far is to downgrade to FF21 and installed Sel 2.1.0 IDE is working fine.  But they've released sel 2.2.0 IDE with the fixes in it for FF22 and can confirm it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem introduced by version 22 of Firefox, and selenium does not work with FireFox 22 as a result.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5554
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5841
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=d1b1fc24f060

It is not resolved in Selenium 2.33 but should be in 2.34.  In the meantime the only solution appears to be to manually downgrade to Firefox 21:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/21.0/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2021.0.exe

Answer (score 0):

The XPath quoting is wrong. You cannot use the same character (apostrophe) for delimiting several things.

```
$sel->click_ok(q(//a[@href="javascript:goTo('overview.html');"]));
```

Code is untested.

Comment: Thanks daxim for correcting the string, however it says it cannot execute the command when it's tested. The error message is: Value does not implement interface Event.  Is there anything else that I'm missing that should come before it to allow it to interact with the Javascript.  If it helps the Xpath from firebug is /html/body/p/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a